# Two Y-axis not aligning correctly

Tags: chart.js

I added two Y-axes into the chart, but for some reason they don't align correctly. The labels to the left are aligned slightly higher than the ones on the right.

[image]

What could be the issue here? I've tried messing around with some options etc, but no luck so far.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your chart is of `type` `'horizontalBar'`, you could define the second y-axis as follows:

```
{
  type: 'category',
  position: 'right', // depends on your choice
  offset: true,
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  }
}
```